# How to filter checkbox by query api in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm making a website that has a filter function before pouring data out... Currently, I'm doing the pretty stupid way of dumping all the data out and putting it in an object and then filtering. I want when I click on it, it will call the api to return according to the params that I pass, but the initial default is that the checkbox is in the all box, it still returns all. Here is my code part....
**Template:**

```js
<template>
  <div class="job">
    <div class="container recruit flex-wrap">
      <div class="job-filter">
        <h3>
          Ngành nghề
          <img
            id="icon-filter"
            @click="showfilter"
            :style="{ display: display.btn_show_filter }"
            src="../assets/recruit/angle-down-svgrepo-com.svg"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            id="icon-close-filter"
            :style="{ display: display.btn_close_filter }"
            @click="closefilter"
            src="../assets/recruit/close-svgrepo-com.svg"
            alt=""
          />
        </h3>

//Handle Filter
        <div
          class="radio-group"
          id="group-filter"
          :style="{ display: display.group_filter }"
        >
          <div
            class="radio-check"
            v-for="(check, index) in checks"
            @click="selectFilter(check)"
            :key="index"
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              :id="index"
              name="fav_language"
              :value="check"
              v-model="selected"
            />
              <label :for="check">{{ check }}</label
            ><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
//End Handle filter


      <div class="search">
        <div class="search-top flex-wrap">
          <h5>{{ totalJobs }} {{ localised("countRecruit") }}</h5>
          <div class="search-input">
            <input
              type="search"
              placeholder="Nhập tên vị trí công việc"
              v-model="search"
            />
            <button @click="searchJob">
              <img src="../assets/recruit/search.svg" alt="" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          id="jobs"
          class="job-item"
          v-for="(item, index) in jobs"
          :key="index"
          :per-page="perPage"
          :current-page="currentPage"
        >
          <router-link
            tag="a"
            :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }"
          >
            <h3 class="mleft-27">{{ item.Name }}</h3>
          </router-link>
          <div class="job-info flex-wrap">
            <div class="job-info-left pleft-27 flex-wrap">
              <div>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/years.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.Exprerience }}</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/luong.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.Salary }}</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/diadiem.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.Headequarters }}</b>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h6>{{ momentTime(item.updatedAt) }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-job flex-wrap">
            <div class="list-info-job">
              <li>{{ item.Content }}</li>
            </div>
            <router-link
              tag="a"
              :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }"
            >
              <button class="btn-detail">Xem chi tiết</button>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="not-found" v-show="showNoData">Not Found</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the js logic I'm dealing with:

```js
<script>
import "../assets/style.css";
import "../assets/job.css";
import job from "../locales/lang";
import request from "@/utils/request";
import moment from "moment";
export default {
  name: "jobs",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      totalJobs: null,
      tickTime: "",
      currentPage: 1,
      showPag: true,
      showNoData: false,
      perPage: 4,
      search: "",
      page: "",
      noData: [],
      checks: [
        "All",
        "Developer",
        "Tester",
        "Designer",
        "Support",
        "Marketing",
        "Other",
      ],
      jobinfos: [],
      showJobs: [],
      selected: "All",
    };
  },
  computed: {  
    
  },
  watch: {
    // selected(newVal) {
    //   if (newVal === "All") {
    //     return this.jobinfos;
    //   } else {
    //     return this.jobinfos.filter((i) => i.Genres === newVal);
    //   }
    // },
    
  },

  async mounted() {
    //API
      this.getJobs();  

    // event enter
    var self = this;
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        self.searchJob();
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    //Call api job information by locale
    async getJobs() {
      await request
        .get(`jobs?_locale=${this.$route.params.locale}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
          this.showJobs = response.data;
          this.totalJobs = response.data.length;
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },

    
   
    //Filter item jobs
    selectFilter(item) {
      this.selected = item;
      if (this.selected == "All") {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos;
      } else {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos.filter((i) => i.Genres === this.selected);
        if (this.showJobs.length > 0) {
          this.showPag = true;
          this.showNoData = false;
        } else {
          this.showPag = false;
          this.showNoData = true;
        }
      }
    },
// method search by filter     
  },
};
</script>
```

As for the backend, I'm using 3rd party cms, it probably already provides enough query params for me, please give me some pseudocode or a way so that when I click on the checkbox, it will call the api to return the records according to the check box ^^ thanks

Comment: It starts with `eventListener` of click and then in the call back function you can care data with `fetch` for calling api.

Comment: Yes but currently I am using Vuejs....

Comment: It look as though when you select a filter it runs the `selectFilter` method.  Sounds like you want to make an API call here requesting filtered results based on the passed in `item` variable.  Is there something more specific you need help figuring out?